# How to organize import and export code for versioned files?

Tags: c++, c, versioning, file-format

If an application has to be able to open (and possibly save) the file format for the last N releases, how should the code be organized sanely so that updating the file format is easy and less error-prone? Assume the file format is in XML, and functions take in objects for export and produce objects for import.

Append a number to the end of each function name, and copy/paste it and increment the number for each new version? That's like maintaining multiple versions of version-controlled functions within source code. Perhaps do some magic at build time?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, supporting import of old versions is a lot easier than export. This is because usually later versions are different because they support more features. Hence saving to an old format may well mean loss of data. Consequently, my experience has only been on supporting import of multiple versions, spanning over a decade.

XML is of course the smart solution. It is designed with this problem in mind. The key point to me is that clean code structure follows from a clean data model. Provided new versions add features and these are represented by support for additional tags, you do not really have to recode handling of existing tags at all.

Now you *could* change the semantics of existing tags, requiring their recoding. Solution: don't do this if you can avoid it. When you add a attribute or tag, make sure you define the default value and then old and new data files are handled seamlessly.

So it seems to me that with care you should be able to avoid many cases where you really have significantly different code for handling the same fields in different file versions. Where this does occur, I am guess there are "special circumstances" (that's life with software). When you design the generic solution you'll have specific use cases in mind, and such special cases may not be handled anyway.

In summary: You'll future proof most efficiently via defining the upgrade path for the data model.

Answer (score 1):

A version number is probably required.

But the best thing is to actually make a design for your XML. And make sure that the XML is structured in an intuitive and natural way. Otherwise the current organisation of your code may leak into the structure of the XML, which makes the XML harder to read for future versions of your product.

When saving enumerated values, don't write the numbers, but the name of the enumerable. If some elements could occur multiple times in principle, but not in your current application, design it as an array in XML. Make sure the numbers you write are in a unit that is logical in the problem domain, and not what your application happens to use right now.

In XML written this way, it should not be hard to support legacy versions of your XML.

**Edit:**

If you make drastic changes, it can be helpful to just implement a legacy data object that reads the legacy xml. Then you write a conversion method to convert from the old data model to the new one. This helps you to a fresh start esp. if the old data model was badly designed.